# How can I add a program to my start menu?

Tags: opensuse

I use suse 12 with very few programs but when I install Komodo it doesn't add itself to my start menu? Why is some program in my start menu and others not?

Comment: What is your windows manager/desktop manager ?

Comment: @Depado: I have voted for the preset KDE desktop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to google it.
There was already an answer about KDE, there it is (it's an exact duplicate I think) https://superuser.com/questions/422072/how-can-i-add-komodo-to-my-start-menu

Comment: No, the question is wrong. I asked for a quickstart posibility. I mean the start menu and not the panel.

Comment: Did you add Komodo to your PATH ? Maybe you could right click on your menu icon and select "menu editor" then manually add the entry in your menu. Should this work or you already tried ? And to answer your question about "why it isn't adding itself in the menu" I think that's because you didn't installed it with the package manager or oneclick install. Did you install it with a tar.gz or something like that ? Manual installation ?

Comment: I see. Right click on menu icon works. I've added Komodo to my developlement programs but there is no icon?

Comment: I think you can add it one manually with KDE. Though I use Gnome 3 so I'm not a professional about that. Right click on your program and check it's property directly in your menu maybe you can set an icon there.

Answer (score 2):

**KDE 4.4.4** *(w.r.t openSUSE 11.3)*

- Right click on the Suse `start button`.
- Click on `Menu editor`.
- Click on `New item` on the horizontal top panel. Fill in the item name.
- Click on the newly added item. Fill in the `command` that it needs to execute (see right side of that window).
- Click `Save` on the horizontal top panel.